# A definition of hatred towards your own nation

Tags: social-psychology, phobia

There are such things as xenophobia, nationalism, etc. In other words, various forms of hating and diminishing the foreign and the foreigners.

My question is, is there a term meaning hatred and disparagement towards your own people or culture? Some kind of your-own-nation-phobia?

I don't mean xenophilia, because that's affection towards foreign, it doesn't mean hatred towards your own. I mean exactly hatred towards your own people/nation/culture/etc.

EDIT1: Just one of the examples of how this phenomena may work. An international conference. A person from, say, Russia, talks to a group people from various countries. Suddenly, another Russian joins the group. Our hero realizes that (either he knew that that person was a Russian beforehand or reads that on their badge) and an anger and disgust start boiling within him. He starts to be prejudiced and a bit aggressive towards his compatriot because that person is his compatriot.

Comment: ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-deprecation

Answer (score 5):

The word "Oikophobia" has several different definitions.  In psychology, it usually means an aversion to home surroundings, or to objects in the home.  However, the British philosopher Roger Scruton coined a new meaning, which is exactly what you are looking for:

> The disposition, in any conflict, to side with 'them' against 'us', and the felt need to denigrate the customs, culture and institutions that are identifiably 'ours'.
>   -  Roger Scruton, quoted on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=oikophobia)

Wikipedia has a more detailed description of the term:

> Scruton uses the term as the antithesis of xenophobia. In his book, Roger Scruton: Philosopher on Dover Beach, Mark Dooley describes oikophobia as centered within the Western academic establishment on "both the common culture of the West, and the old educational curriculum that sought to transmit its humane values." This disposition has grown out of, for example, the writings of Jacques Derrida and of Michel Foucault's "assault on 'bourgeois' society result[ing] in an 'anti-culture' that took direct aim at holy and sacred things, condemning and repudiating them as oppressive and power-ridden."
>
> "Derrida is a classic oikophobe in so far as he repudiates the longing for home that the Western theological, legal, and literary traditions satisfy. . . . Derrida's deconstruction seeks to block the path to this 'core experience' of membership, preferring instead a rootless existence founded 'upon nothing.'"
>
> An extreme aversion to the sacred and the thwarting of the connection of the sacred to the culture of the West is described as the underlying motif of oikophobia; and not the substitution of Judeo-Christianity by another coherent system of belief. The paradox of the oikophobe seems to be that any opposition directed at the theological and cultural tradition of the West is to be encouraged even if it is "significantly more parochial, exclusivist, patriarchal, and ethnocentric."  Scruton described "a chronic form of oikophobia [which] has spread through the American universities, in the guise of political correctness."
>
> Scruton's usage has been taken up by some American political commentators to refer to what they see as a rejection of traditional American culture by the liberal elite. In August 2010 James Taranto wrote a column in the Wall Street Journal entitled Oikophobia, Why the liberal elite finds Americans revolting in which he criticized supporters of the proposed Islamic center in New York as oikophobes who were defending Muslims who aimed to "exploit the 9/11 atrocity".
>   -  [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oikophobia#Scruton.27s_usage)

Answer (score 3):

There is some research in social psychology that has investigated when people dislike a group they belong to. Thus, this research is more general in that it is not limited to nationality, but about any kind of social group.

Usually, people have a tendency for ingroup bias, that is, they prefer their own group over other groups (outgroups). One important theoretical perspective that has guided much research on this phenomenon is [Social Identity Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_identity_theory), which posits that people derive their self-concept from the groups they belong to, and strive for positive distinctiveness from other groups.

Sometimes, however, people have a strong dislike for their own group, e.g., because these groups are stigmatized, because a larger ingroup discriminates a smaller subgroup they belong to, because an ingroup violates important personal moral standards, or when people move to high status positions in disadvantaged groups (for a review, see Becker & Tausch, 2014). This phenomenon has been labeled with different terms such as "**ingroup hate**", "**outgroup favoritism**", or "**disidentification**".

To my knowledge, the most comprehensive account of explicit dislike of ingroups has been proposed by Becker and Tausch (2014), who have developed a scale to capture this phenomenon. They distinguish between different components of **disidentification** and show that their scale can predict negative emotional and behavioral reactions toward the ingroup. Citing from their abstract:

> This research introduces a multi-component model of ingroup disidentification that distinguishes three disidentification components (detachment, dissatisfaction, and dissimilarity). In Studies 1a (N = 168) and 1b (N = 215), the authors developed a measurement scale that assesses these components, and examined alternative factorial structures. Study 2 (N = 115) provides evidence that the disidentification scale performs better at distinguishing between disidentification and nonidentification than an established identification scale. Using additional data from Studies 1b and 2, Studies 3a and 3b examined emotions and behavioral intentions as correlates of disidentification and revealed that the disidentification components predict negative ingroup-directed behavioral intentions (active harm, passive harm, and passive facilitation) and identity concealment over and above measures of identification.

**References**

Becker, J. C., & Tausch, N. (2014). When group memberships are negative: The concept, measurement, and behavioral implications of psychological disidentification. Self and Identity, 13(3), 294–321. http://doi.org/10.1080/15298868.2013.819991

Answer (score 0):

I like the word misanthropy...

Misanthropy is the general hatred, distrust or disdain of the human species or human nature. A misanthrope or misanthropist is someone who holds such views or feelings. The word's origin is from the Greek words μῖσος (misos, "hatred") and ἄνθρωπος (anthrōpos, "man, human"). The condition is often confused with asociality.

Comment: Well, it's different. It's a hatred towards all humans. I'm looking for hatred towards people of one's own nation, without necessarily present hatred towards foreigners.